# Help to proof that squared integrable functions form a hilbert space.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

Marcus here.

I am currently trying to understand the concept Hilbert space, specifically for squared integrable functions. The definition of a hilbert space is "A inner product space $( \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle, E)$ is said to be complete if every cauchy sequence is convergent. Then $( \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle, E)$ is also said to be a hilbert space". A standard example is that the set of squared integrable functions is a hilbert space, that is
\begin{align*}
L^2(\Omega) = \{ f:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}:\int_{\Omega} |f|^2 dx < \infty\}
\end{align*}
For $f,g \in L^2(\Omega)$ we define the inner product $\langle f , g \rangle = \int_{\Omega}f^*g \ dx$, where $f^*$ is the complex conjugated of $f$, this inner product space, $( \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle, L^2(\Omega))$, forms a hilbert space. I try to use the hilbert space theory to understand the wave equation equipped with the dirichlet boundary condition on $\Omega$ for a drum, thus in my case I am interested in the case where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. But I am stuck with the basic question why is $( \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle, L^2(\Omega))$ a hilbert space in the first place? I do not know much about functional analysis and measure theory, thus I am interested in a proof using basic principles, so the questions is do such a basic proof exist?

Comment: This is not an inner product space exactly. You need to quotient out by a relation to make it one ($f\sim g$ if $f=g$ almost everywhere). Wikipedia has a very good section on this on its $L^p$ space wiki.

Comment: Measure theory is unavoidable here.  In order to get a Hilbert space, you *have* to take the set of all *measurable* square-integrable functions (mod almost everywhere equivalence), where the integral is understood to be the Lebesgue integral.  If you take a more "basic" notion of integration, e.g. considering the set of all functions whose square is Riemann integrable, you do not get a Hilbert space because it won't be complete.  This is one of the major motivations for using Lebesgue measure theory in the first place.